# Column Constraint or comma expected, got TEXT

Tags: android, sqlite

I am pretty confident I have formatted this correctly, as it's basically an exact duplicate of another statement I'm using (which works fine), but I'm getting an error stating

```
'(', ')' <column constraint> or comma expected, got 'TEXT'
```

and a red underline under 'TEXT' in line:

```
+ RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_CONTROL_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
```

Like I said, I've got basically an exact duplicate of this statement working elsewhere.

Here's the one that does not work:

```
String sSQL;
        sSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + RecentFileWaypointContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_CONTROL_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_INSURED_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_CUSTOMER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_ADDRESS1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_ADDRESS2 + " TEXT, "
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_CITY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_STATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_ZIPCODE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(sSQL);
```

for comparison, here's the one that works just fine:

```
String sSQL;
        sSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + UserWaypointContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + UserWaypointContract.Columns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
                + UserWaypointContract.Columns.USER_WAYPOINT_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserWaypointContract.Columns.USER_WAYPOINT_ADDRESS1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserWaypointContract.Columns.USER_WAYPOINT_ADDRESS2 + " TEXT, "
                + UserWaypointContract.Columns.USER_WAYPOINT_CITY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserWaypointContract.Columns.USER_WAYPOINT_STATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserWaypointContract.Columns.USER_WAYPOINT_ZIPCODE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(sSQL);
```

(Also, there are in two different classes, so the use of sSQL in both places isnt the issue)

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `RecentFileWaypointContract.Columns.RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_CONTROL_NUMBER`? What is the resulting value of `sSQL`?

Comment: public static final String RECENT_FILE_WAYPOINT_CONTROL_NUMBER = "Control number";

Comment: Change to: ` "[Control number]"`. SQLite does not allow spaces in the names of columns or tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have column names with whitespace in them. Replace `"Control number"` with `"Control_number"`, `"ControlNumber"`, `"controlNumber"`, or something similar.